# Android/XML Aligning imageViews above EditTexts

Tags: xml, android-layout

I'm just trying to align an imageView above an edittext. The edit texts are aligned to be at the bottom of the activity. I put the two pairs inside A relative layout and just tried aligning the image to be above, but that doesn't work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW8Rx.png
[image]

> 

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_above="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:hint="Your name"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/edit2"
    android:hint="Your number"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to point the arrow towards the EditText then the following layout may solve your problem. To demonstrate your idea, I have just created a rough layout with some hardcoded values. But while developing your project, you should follow the standard guidelines provided by Google.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Your Name"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Your Number"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: I have given the screenshot below. Tell me whether you want this type of layout or not.]

Comment: you are 200% awesome. Thanks for taking the time to explain all of this!

Comment: Well man, it felt good to be able to help you out. Thanks for your acknowledgement. :)

Answer (score 1):

the solution of your problem is **FrameLayout**. In your code in the place of **RelativeLayout** use **FrameLayout**. First place the **ImageView** inside the **FrameLayout**, then place the EditText over there. That will solve your problem. Please let me know if I'm able to help you.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:hint="Your name"
            />
    </FrameLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit2"
    android:hint="Your number"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Trying this, I get the arrow going directly OVER the edit text.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want the arrow over the EditText. But from your design it's like that only. Please explain it in more detail.

Comment: I think I'm being very unclear with what I mean of over. I would like to get the arrow to point towards the EditText by being positioned above. The code above puts the arrow to "overlap" the EditText.